# How to push data from excel spreadsheet to any application

Tags: excel, amos, vba

I need to push some 3000 entries from excel to an application called AMOS  so could it be possible by excel vba or through some other utilities or applications.

Comment: That would depend on the capability of AMOS.  Better to ask them

Comment: To push data from Excel spreadsheet to any application is possible using any programming which is able handling Excel and the goal application as well.

Answer (score 0):

AMOS doesn't support Excel data being programmatically "pushed in to it".

Instead, **save the Excel data as file type `CSV (Comma delimited)` and then import into AMOS**.  You can create a `CSV` file [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419828/how-to-create-a-separate-csv-file-from-vba) if necessary.

AMOS can also import Excel 97-2003 `XLS` files, but not `XLSX`.  You can save a newer file as `XLS` in Excel by choosing file type `Excel 97-2003 Workbook (*.xls)`.

More info [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_import_data_to_AMOS).