# Save the contents of a cell to a csv without quotes in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a csv file (without quotes) using VBA - the only contents of the file should be the value in the cell named "MetricValue".

```
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim PathName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set Range.Value = MetricValue
    FileName = "filename.csv"
    PathName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    ws.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=PathName & "\" & FileName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

I know I've stuffed up something with setting the range, but can't figure out why. Everything I've tried to get to work only outputs with quote marks around the value. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are there commas in your values?

Comment: `Set ws = Range.Value = MetricValue` - what's that's supposed to do?

Comment: @BigBen it's meant to set the value that I'd like to export.

Comment: @PGSystemTester no, there are no commas, it's just a number eg. "-34123.32"

Comment: `Set Range.Value = MetricValue` is still problematic... what's the code you're actually running?

Comment: @BigBen - this is the code I'm trying to run.  I'm trying to save the value in the named cell "MetricValue' (eg. -4321.12)  as the only value inside a csv.  But I can't seem to set that to work.  I know it's problematic, but I can't work out why.

Comment: The code as you've provided it won't run (`Set` is for object variables). Can you make your question a [reprex]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question is confusing because what you really seem to be wanting to do is save a single value as a CSV. The quotes that are being created, are likely from other parts of your file. There's probably better methods to accomplish what your overall objective is. Here's a good [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419828/how-to-create-a-separate-csv-file-from-vba) on CSV files via excel that might be useful.

Regardless, here are two solutions to save your Named Range value as a CSV file using a macro. Make sure the named range is at the workbook level (not sheet).

### Option One

```
Sub MakeASingleValueCSVFile()
Dim FileName As String: FileName = "filename.csv"
Dim PathName As String: PathName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim finalValue As Double: finalValue = Range("MetricValue").Value

    
Dim iFileNum As Long
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open PathName & "\" & FileName For Output As iFileNum

Print #iFileNum, finalValue
Close #iFileNum
End Sub
```

That has some spacing issues you might not like.

### Option 2

(updated with more dynamic solution that initial question)

```
Const FileName As String = "filename2"
Const namedRange As String = "MetricValue" 'make sure at workbook level
Dim PathName As String: PathName = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Dim pullRNG As Range: Set pullRNG = Range(namedRange)
Dim wkBK As Workbook: Set wkBK = Application.Workbooks.Add

With wkBK
    .Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(pullRNG.Rows.Count, pullRNG.Columns.Count) = pullRNG.Value
    .SaveAs PathName & "\" & FileName, xlCSV
    .Close
End With
```